# RSS feed for major Steam sales?

Tags: steam

Is there somewhere I can subscribe that would only show 40% off or more game sales? Steam is a must; bonus points for aggregating multiple sites/stores.

I'm rarely catching the sales on steam, and I imagine steam isn't the only company doing really nice occasional special sales.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Steam RSS news feed link is [here](http://store.steampowered.com/feeds/news.xml). Steamprices.com also runs a [variety of feeds](http://www.steamprices.com/us/feed) based on your region and can also provide information on permanent price changes.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cheapshark.com/ gives a good overview of different deals from different developers. Next to that there are several filter options, such as maximum price.

The [browse page](http://www.cheapshark.com/browse) now has an RSS feed. (check the RSS icon at the bottom right of the filters)

Comment: Nice link, looks like a reasonable site - shame it doesn't have an RSS feed though I see it's mentioned on the wish list.

Answer (score 0):

UK-based [SavyGamer](http://savygamer.co.uk/) does a good job of keeping track of deals on video games and lets you break down feeds by platform. The [PC feed](http://savygamer.co.uk/category/deals/pc/feed/) can be further broken down into [retail](http://savygamer.co.uk/category/deals/pc/retail/feed/) or [digital distribution](http://savygamer.co.uk/category/deals/pc/dd/feed/) feeds.

No Steam-only feed, but it usually mentions if retail or non-Steam digital titles can be registered on Steam after purchase and covers special sales by other companies.

No idea how well it works for other regions I'm afraid. :(